# Proof that convergence in $r$-th mean implies convergence of the $r$-th moments

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(Z_n)$ be a sequence of random variables and $Z$ another random variable. I am trying to prove the fact that convergence in $r$-th mean implies convergence of the $r$-th moments.

That is, if $Z_n \overset{r.m.}{\rightarrow} Z$ and $\text{E}|Z|^r < \infty$ then $\text{E}|Z_n|^r \rightarrow \text{E}|Z|^r$ where my defition of convergence in $r$-th mean is
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \text{E}|Z_n - Z|^r = 0
\end{equation}

It feels like it should be simple but I am having a hard time proving this fact.

Comment: You have to use the lower triangle inequality for the $L^p$ norm: $$\big| \|u\|_p-\|v\|_p \big| \leq \|u-v\|_p$$ for any $u,v \in L^p$, $p \geq 1$.